# What is the fastest way to set up a DAG using a list of tuples, where first and second elements represent neighbor connections?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Let's say I have a list of tuples:  `[(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(4,5)....`.
In this list of tuples, the second element is always strictly greater than the first element.
Let `x_i` be the first element of tuple `i`. And `y_i` be the second element of tuple `i`.
I'd like to create a graph in the following way:
1). A single tuple is a single vertex.
2). If two tuples `i` and `j`, have `y_i==x_j`, then a directed arc should exist from `i` to `j`.

The result will be a directed acyclic graph.  However, I'm not able to find an easy way to input this into `networkx`.  The usual ways are `edgelist`, etc.,  but I don't see how the situation above will be treated appropriately by that.  Is there an easy way to created a DAG using the inputs I just described?

Answer (score 0):

Instanciate a `DiGraph` and add the nodes ([`add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph..html)), the use a dictionary to identify the nodes linked to a particular `j`, then add the edges ([`add_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html)):

```
lst = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(4,5)]

d = {}
for i,j in lst:
    d.setdefault(i, set()).add((i, j))
# {0: {(0, 1), (0, 2)}, 1: {(1, 3)}, 4: {(4, 5)}}

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(lst)
G.add_edges_from(((i, j), k) for i, j in lst
                 if j in d for k in d[j])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I'm deeply sorry if the question is not fully clear.  This doesn't seem to be exactly what I need, but it is close!  A single tuple `(x_i, y_i)`, should have an incoming edge *for all tuples that have `x_i` as its second element in the tuple*. As I said in the question `(0,1)` represents a single vertex - not an edge.  

Your second example almost seems right, except the picture is misleading.  It should have $(0,1)$ and $(1,3)$ as labels on the vertices.  And also, $(0,2)$ and $(4,5)$ should be isolated vertices.

Comment: @underdog987 can you be explicit and provide a schematic of the expected output?